# Vue public folder images in sass

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vue-cli

In my Vue-CLI project, all images are located inside `public/media` folder.

In Vue files, I was able to refer to public folder images with path `/media/image.png`

When I am trying to set a background in my sass

```css
background-image: url('/media/image.png');
```

It throws the error below:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/media/image.png' in 'myPath/src'
```

Look like by default sass is looking for images inside `/src` folder.

Is there a way to use images from `/public` folder?

Comment: Good question, Vue docs say that absolute paths should not be attempted to be bundled up by webpack and instead served from the dist folder, and yet webpack tries to bundle them for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
background-image: url('~@/media/image.png');
```

Key here is using ~@ as a prefix. URLs prefixed with ~ are treated as a module request.

Comment: Does this method require any additional configuration? Still doesn't work for me, returns same error

Answer (score 0):

This message seems to be caused by [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/)

css-loader has a "url" option that may be set to false to prevent it from parsing paths.

> If set to false, css-loader will not parse any paths specified in url or image-set

In vue.config.js, you configure this as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      css: {
        url: false;
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Please note that blindly using `url: false` could stop your project from including some static assets, such as fonts, in your build artifacts. You should pass a call-back function if this becomes a problem for you, and you can't import your other assets a different way.

It may be worth reconsidering how you import your static assets such as images, for example by including them in an `src/assets` directory as part of your project, so they are (by default) copied into your dist (or whatever you may have changed the name to) directory for deployment.